# Unit test wpf application exit

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I wrote a simple Shutdown command in C#/WPF and try to create a unit test for them by triggering the Exit event but the event isnt called because i create the application at hand i guess.

My Code looks something like that (simplified for demonstration)

```
var application = new System.Windows.Application();
var exitHappened = default(bool);
application.Exit += (object sender, System.Windows.ExitEventArgs e) => exitHappened = true;
application.Shutdown();
Assert.IsTrue(exitHappened);
```

I need to create an application instance because there is no Application.Current in my test assembly available but seems to be i have to initialize the application in some way. Do i?

Comment: You don't need unit tests for such things. This is a part of automated test, where clicking button and checking if SUT is closed makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver) to automated testing of WPF UI and various other desktop applications. It is developed by Microsoft. But it has quiet a bit of learning curve if you are entirely new to it.